# Bootstrap 2.3.2 template loads narrow then adjusts in IE8 - how to debug?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

**Problem**

I'm having a problem with the way my bootstrap web page is loading in IE8. On page load it loads the page template at a width that is too narrow for the browser size, and after a few seconds it suddenly adjusts to the correct width. It makes the page load appear clunky. This doesn't happen in Chrome.

**Background**

I work in a company where IE7 and IE8 are the most used browsers and I need to build a new template for our internal websites. I'm using Bootstrap 2.3.2 to construct the template because this is compatible with IE7+.

**How to fix?**

I'd like to be able to post some cut-down code that replicates the issue I'm having so that you can see what I mean, but I'm struggling to identify what's causing the issue in order to provide that code! I've tried removing stylesheets/scripts etc one at a time to identify what might be causing the issue, but it seems to be inconsistent. I was wondering if anyone has

a) seen this kind of thing before and knows what the likely cause is OR

b) any tips on how to debug and locate the cause myself?

I've downloaded Fiddler 2 and thought that if I could spot what's happening at the exact moment that the page changes from being narrow to wide I might be able to figure it out, but I'm not having any luck with that method. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Katie

Comment: I am struggling with the exact same behavior with Bootstrap 3.1.1 and IE8. Some `col-md-2` columns starts "collapsed" and then after one second adjust to their correct width.

Comment: It may be respond.js taking some time to parse media-queries : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680215/do-i-have-to-include-respond-js-in-the-header.